# Cannot find -lpython3.5 -> Eclipse CPP

Tags: python, c++, eclipse

I'm trying to run Python commands inside a C++ Project using eclipse.

I've already included "/usr/include/python3.5" in my Include paths and in the Library search path for Cross G++ Linker. In Miscellaneous from Cross G++ Linker I've add -lpython3.5.

With these configurations, my build looks like: **g++ -L/usr/include/python3.5/ -lpython3.5 -o "CppPyTest"  ./src/CppPyTest.o**

However, I got the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5
makefile:45: recipe for target 'CppPyTest' failed

If I remove the -lpython3.5 I got the error:

undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'

My full code is:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {     
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isn't this `-lpython35` (without the dot)

Comment: Check which `.a` files are available in the specified lib directory. `-l<xxx>` is shortcut for `-l lib<xxx>.a`.

Comment: I don't know why, but the directory ld in /usr/bin does not exists. It should be default, shouldn't it ? I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to compile and link your code.
This gives the proper paramters for eighter python from the package-manager or the anaconda package.

Code (made Python 3 compatible):

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {     
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Calling (for anaconda)

```
g++ -I/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -L /opt/anaconda3/lib -lpython3.7m CppPyTest.cpp
```

or (python from package manager)

```
g++ -I/usr/include/python3.6m/ -lpython3.6m CppPyTest.cpp
```

creates an executateble a.out in the folder.

We can execute `a.out` by

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/anaconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./a.out
```

giving the output:

```
Today is Tue Jul  7 14:56:31 2020
```

To help you adjust the paths properly, here the content of the anaconda folders:

```
$ ls /opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython*
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.a
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.nolto.a
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.so
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.so


$ ls /opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/
Python-ast.h           errcode.h          object.h       pymem.h
Python.h               eval.h             objimpl.h      pyport.h
abstract.h             fileobject.h       odictobject.h  pystate.h
accu.h                 fileutils.h        opcode.h       pystrcmp.h
asdl.h                 floatobject.h      osdefs.h       pystrhex.h
ast.h                  frameobject.h      osmodule.h     pystrtod.h
bitset.h               funcobject.h       parsetok.h     pythonrun.h
bltinmodule.h          genobject.h        patchlevel.h   pythread.h
boolobject.h           graminit.h         pgen.h         pytime.h
bytearrayobject.h      grammar.h          pgenheaders.h  rangeobject.h
bytes_methods.h        greenlet           py_curses.h    setobject.h
bytesobject.h          import.h           pyarena.h      sip.h
cellobject.h           internal           pyatomic.h     sliceobject.h
ceval.h                intrcheck.h        pycapsule.h    structmember.h
classobject.h          iterobject.h       pyconfig.h     structseq.h
code.h                 listobject.h       pyctype.h      symtable.h
codecs.h               longintrepr.h      pydebug.h      sysmodule.h
compile.h              longobject.h       pydtrace.h     token.h
complexobject.h        marshal.h          pyerrors.h     traceback.h
context.h              memoryobject.h     pyexpat.h      tupleobject.h
datetime.h             metagrammar.h      pyfpe.h        typeslots.h
descrobject.h          methodobject.h     pyhash.h       ucnhash.h
dictobject.h           modsupport.h       pylifecycle.h  unicodeobject.h
dtoa.h                 moduleobject.h     pymacconfig.h  warnings.h
dynamic_annotations.h  namespaceobject.h  pymacro.h      weakrefobject.h
enumobject.h           node.h             pymath.h
```